# How to get Azure Cloud Service tutorial to work

Tags: proxy, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I have been following the Azure Email Service tutorial (aka Azure Cloud Service Tutorial) [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-storage-1-overview/).

Following the instructions in [step 2](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-storage-2-download-run/), I downloaded the project, and was able to run it locally. Again following the instructions, I then created an Azure Storage account and Cloud Service, and configured my application to use them.

However, when I got to "Test the application configured to use your storage account", I got an exception when I tried to run the application. The exception was raised in the WorkerRoleB project, in the `OnStart` method, at this line:

```
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
```

The exception was a `StorageException`:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

...and the inner exception was a `WebException`:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

I tried adding the following to the .config file for WorkerRoleB:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

...and I no longer got the exception in WorkerRoleB, but I then got an identical exception (on a similar line of code) in WorkerRoleA. So, I added the same config fragment to WorkerRoleA. Once again, this meant that I no longer got the exception in WorkerRoleA.

However, having added that config fragment to WorkerRoleA and WorkerRoleB, I *still* was not able to run the application. When hitting "run", the browser opened up a window with no content shown (but with the "loading" indicator spinning), and eventually after about 30 secs, I got an exception in the Global.asax of the MvcWebRole project.

The exception was raised at the following line (look familiar?):

```
mailingListTable.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Once again, the exception was a `StorageException`:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

...but this time the inner exception was a `SocketException`:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 168.61.61.16:443

I'm at a loss as to what to do now. I don't actually even know whether the proxy-related changes I've made to the WorkerRoleA and WorkerRoleB projects were correct, since although they appeared to move things forward, I've not actually seen the project run yet. Any suggestions?

---

Update: I found a blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/narahari/archive/2011/12/21/azure-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond-after-a-period-of-time-or-established-connection-failed-because-connected-host-has-failed-to-respond-x-x-x-x-x-quot.aspx) that seems to give an explanation for why I'm seeing the "connection attempt failed" error, which is that I'm likely behind a proxy or firewall that only allows traffic from authenticated users, whereas Azure/IIS configures the AppPool (for the WebRole) to run under "NetworkService".

A couple of the suggested resolutions looked viable, but I couldn't get either of them to work:

1. **Comment out the  section in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file** - when I tried to do this, the project would not build, because the .csdef file no longer adhered to the schema. (In any case, my .csdef file didn't really seem to have anything of note in that file, so I was skeptical that this would work anyway).
2. **Programmatically change the identity of the AppPool** - I tried using the sample code provided, but it failed when it tried to find the relevant site (`ServerManager.Sites[xxx]` returned `null`, leading to a `NullReferenceException`).

Comment: Downvoter: how can I improve my question?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you tried all workarounds listed in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/narahari/archive/2011/12/21/azure-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond-after-a-period-of-time-or-established-connection-failed-because-connected-host-has-failed-to-respond-x-x-x-x-x-quot.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that's the same post I listed in my question.